# If $x^2 \equiv -2$ mod $p$ is not solvable and $p|(a^2+2b^2)$, then show $p|a$ and $p|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is my first number theory class so I'm having a bit of a hard time getting started.

Based on the given statement, I can say $a^2 \equiv -2b^2$ mod $p$ but I don't know where to proceed with this.
Maybe I can say suppose $p$ doesnt divide $a$ so $gcd(a,p)=1$ so there exists an $\overline{a}$ and $a\overline{a} \equiv 1$ mod $p$ ?

Also not sure what the first part on the congruence not being solvable can provide but I think I can infer that $p>2$ since $p=2$ would indeed be solvable.

Any hints or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: If $p\nmid b$ and $a^2\equiv-2b^2$ what can you say about the residue class of $(a/b)^2$? As always, division by $b$ is to be interpreted as muliplication by the inverse $b'$ such that $bb'\equiv1$.

Comment: I might be wrong but does that give $(ab')^2 \equiv -2$? do we then say that this means the congruence system is actually solvable and say it's a contradiction? I still don't get how this can prove $p|a$ though...

Comment: That's what I was aiming at, indeed. Proceed!

Comment: Hint: $ $ if $\,\color{#c00}{a\not\equiv 0}\,$ then $a^{-1}$ exists so $\,a^2 \equiv -2 b^2\overset{\div\, b^2}\Longrightarrow (a/b)^2 = -2\,$ contra hypothesis, therefore we must have $\,\color{#c00}{a\equiv 0},\,$ so $\, -2b^2\equiv a^2\equiv 0\Rightarrow b\equiv0.\ $ Same is true in any *field* where $\,2\neq 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Start from $$a^2=-2b^2.$$ If one of $b$ is $0$ mod $p$ then so must $a$, or equivalently, $a|p$ and $b|p$ and so you would be done.

So now assume that $p$ does not divide $b$. Then note that $b^2$ is a nonzero square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^×$ and so $b^{-2}$ is an element in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^×$.
So multiply both sides of
$$a^2 \equiv_p -2b^2$$ by $b^{-2}$ to get
$$a^2b^{-2} \equiv_p -2.$$
So then $a$ and $b$ together must satisfy this above equation. But $a^2b^{-2}$ is itself a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^×$, so then, rewrite $a^2b^{-2} = x^2$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then $x$ must satisfy the equation
$$x^2 \equiv_p -2.$$ As there is no such $x$ by hypothesis, it follows that $b$ must be $0$ mod $p$, and so as noted above so must $a$ be $0$ mod $p$, or equivalently $p|a$ and $p|b$.